Setting txt layer labels to different colours depending on values
I have found Setting different colors based on value when labeling using QGIS which should do what I want but I don't see the formula Icon highlighted in the answer.
QGIS version is Firenze.
This is what I see:


Click the data define override icon to the right of the color drop down, then select edit then follow the linked answer
